# E/FirebaseInstanceId( 8475): Failed to get FIS auth token

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

E/FirebaseInstanceId( 8475): Failed to get FIS auth token
E/FirebaseInstanceId( 8475): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException: Firebase Installations Service is unavailable. Please try again later.

I am facing this problem. Because of this firebase messaging is not working. I am facing this error on the my live app also.

I tried to:
flutter clean
Build project again
redownloaded the google-services.json file
Tried to change the firebase dependencies.

"But it didn't work".

Comment: Make sure that the API key used in the google-services.json file is [unrestricted](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/API_KEY_RESTRICTIONS.md#what-do-i-need-to-do) to allow the usage of the Firebase Installations API. Or, if you implement API key restriction, make sure that Firebase Installations API is included on it. And, if you are using App restriction, make sure to use the correct app signing certificate.